# How to post value from autocomplete instead of text?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

This is my C# Code:

```
public JsonResult FillUsers(string term)
    {
        var Retailers = from us in db.Users
                        join pi in db.UserPersonalInfoes on us.ID equals pi.UserID into t
                        from rt in t.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where us.Status == true
                        select new
                        {
                            ID = us.ID,
                            Username = us.Username + ":( " + (rt == null ? String.Empty : rt.FirstName) + " )"
                        };

        List<string> UsersList;
        UsersList = Retailers.Where(x => x.Username.Contains(term)).Select(y => y.Username).Take(10).ToList();

        return Json(UsersList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
                 @Html.TextBox("ddlUser", null, new { @id = "ddlUser", @class = "form-control" })
             </div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#ddlUser").autocomplete({
        source: '@Url.Action("FillUsers", "FirebaseNotification")',
        select:function(event, ui)
        {
            var id = ui.item.ID;
            var name = ui.item.Username;
        }
        });
    });
```

I want show 'username' in text field but when form will be post I want to send 'ID'. Instead of that I am getting username.

Comment: You can use Hidden field to save that UserID

Comment: Why not use a a combo-box ? https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox .  Because unlike <select>, <input> display text is the value. Where as for <select> you can have different value and display text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that you might need an additional hidden field in which you store the id when a selection is made:

```
$("#ddlUser").autocomplete({
    source: '@Url.Action("FillUsers", "FirebaseNotification")',
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var id = ui.item.ID;
        $('#selectedUserId').val(id);
    }
});
```

Now when the form is submitted you will ignore the `username` value coming from the text input field, but rather take the hidden field value:

```
@Html.Hidden("selectedUserId", null, new { id = "selectedUserId" })
```

Comment: why i get undefined when alerting var id ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#ddlUser").keyup(function (e) { 
  if (e.which != 13) { 
    $("#hfUserID").val("0"); 
  } 
  $("#ddlUser").autocomplete({ 
    source: function (request, response) { ... }, 
    select: function (e, i) {   
      $("#hfUserID").val(i.item.val);
      $("#ddlUser").val(i.item.label); 
    }, 
    minLength: 1 
                                         
    }); 
  });
```